# Express POST fails to recognize Strings

Tags: javascript, express, post, rest-client

ok, I'm trying to build my first REST API, and have the schema set up, and try to use the rest client in VS Code to test it. Some how all the string input in my json body are not recognized instead they are null. I'm not sure what went wrong, any suggestions regarding where I should double check that could go wrong?

models/wordDetailSchema.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const WordDetailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    // required: true,
  },
  partOfSpeech: {
    type: String,
    // required: true,
  },
  definition: {
    type: String,
    // required: [true, "Word meaning is required"],
  },
  synonyms: {
    type: [String],
  },
  examples: {
    type: [String],
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("WordDetail", WordDetailSchema);
```

routes/wordDetails.js

```js
const expree = require("express");
const router = expree.Router();
const WordDetail = require("../models/WordDetailSchema");

//Creating one
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const wordDetail = new WordDetail({
    name: req.body.name,
    partOfSpeech: req.body.partOfSpeech,
    definition: req.body.definition,
    synonyms: req.body.synonym,
    examples: req.body.example,
  });
  try {
    const newWordDetail = await wordDetail.save();
    res.status(201).json(newWordDetail);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

Scripts that I used to post using REST Client:
route.rest

```js
POST http://localhost:3001/wordDetails

Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name" : "can",
    "partOfSpeech" : "verb",
    "definition" : "be able to.",
    "synonyms" : [],
    "examples" : ["they can run fast"],
}
```

Server.js:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", (error) => console.error(error));
db.once("open", () => console.log("Connected to database"));

app.use(express.json());

const wordsRouter = require("./routes/words");
const wordDetailRouter = require("./routes/wordDetails");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/words", wordsRouter);
app.use("/wordDetails", wordDetailRouter);
app.listen(3001, () => console.log("Server Started"));
```

And the result is:

```js
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 70
ETag: W/"46-Hq/hIWt5lGAlv2gNJQxk5mUEYHg"
Date: Fri, 10 Sep 2021 04:41:14 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "synonyms": [],
  "examples": [],
  "_id": "613ae1eac4b78ca3080dbed8",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try using

```js
app.use(express.json()); //Used to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
```

because you no longer need the body parser module if
the verison of express is 4.16+

Comment: Thanks but It still doesn't work, maybe it's some bug in the rest-client?

Comment: no it still not posting the strings I put in the JSON. I think is how I USE REST-CLIENT is incorrect? I use postman and it can post it successfully.